# Proper values for PSOperationsMonitoringPropertie when using Set/New-AzureRmIotHub

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-iot-hub

We are attempting to create an Azure IOT Hub via PowerShell.  The `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.IotHub.Models.PSOperationsMonitoringProperties` parameter, (`-OperationsMonitoringProperties`) is a datatype that contains a single member, of type `Dictionary<string,string>`.

I believe it's key/value pairs, where the key is from the set of `category` values shown in the examples at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-operations-monitoring.

I do not know what to supply for the 'value' portion, however.
I believe the possible values are some spelling of the words `{None, Verbose, Error}`.  Can anyone say what the possible values are?  Passing the value `"Error"` had success, but not with other words.  For example `"Verbose"` returns a 400 / BadRequest from the `Set-AzureRmIotHub` Powershell Command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values are "None", "Information", and "Error". Example below:

```
$hub = Get-AzureRmIotHub
$op = $hub.Properties.OperationsMonitoringProperties
$op.OperationMonitoringEvents["DeviceIdentityOperations"] = "None" # None|Information|Error
$hubupdated = Set-AzureRmIotHub `
  -ResourceGroupName getStartedWithIoTHub_rg `
  -Name getStartedWithAnIoTHub `
  -OperationsMonitoringProperties $op
$hubupdated.Properties.OperationsMonitoringProperties
```

Comment: What are the possible values for the `key`?

Comment: Note:  Played with Portal IOT Operations Monitoring Blade.  Setting monitoring category `"DeviceIdentityOperations"` to "Verbose" on the blade results in value  `"Error, Information"` for the `$op.OperationMonitoringEvents["DeviceIdentityOperations"]`.

Kinda wish I'd thought to play with the portal and then calls `Get-AzureRmIotHub` before posting, but perhaps others will benefit.

Comment: Note also:  The possible values for `key` as emitted by `Get-AzureRmIotHub` are: `"DeviceIdentityOperations", "DeviceTelemetry", "C2DCommands", "None", "Connections", "FileUploadOperations", "Routes"`.  The `value` for the `"None"` category comes back as `"None"`.  I've no idea what the affect of setting the `"None"` category to anything besides `"None"` would be.